# Android app as gift

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to make my paid Android application for free for certain accounts? If so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: Please go to Android Market and request this feature:
http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/static.py?page=suggestions.cs&issue=1238102&bucket=1238454

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you can send the .apk to anyone you like and let them install it that way.

Comment: +1 Yes exactly, you can give URL of APK file. So once user click on the link, APK will be downloaded in the device.

Comment: 1+ this is exactly what I would suggest

Comment: And this is how your app will end up on torrent.. Also that user will not be able to update the app

Answer (score 2):

send the .apk to anyone will soon be boring if you do a lot of updating, I advise you personally reimburse the person if there is not much one to give as a gift application, but it costs a little, personally I would lean more to the code to send the person to unlock the application. It's easy to code, should not change from one version to another, so a plus for the developer and user. For if it is against a unique code, you do not say that a user gives it to everyone, so I would advise to create a simple algorithm that will generate the code from the account record in the phone example and the user can benefit on multiple devices and this should prevent any drift abuse

Answer (score 1):

Sadly no. I really hope they implement some sort of Market gift card system soon.

Answer (score 1):

What kimi said - but...
If you only want to distribute your app via the Android Market (so users can benefit from auto updates etc.) you could also think about making the app free to download from the Market, but implementing In-App Payment. You could lock the app after a few days of usage (keep track of the time via a webservice) and after that force users to pay for the app via In-App-Payment OR type in a gift code (that will unlock the app without paying).